# Header is transitive?

Tags: c

If I have 3 files:

```
header1.h
header2.h
header3.h
```

And I did `#include "header1.h"` in header2.h, then if I do `#include "header2.h"` in header3.h does header3.h have header1.h's declarations?

Comment: Unless some conditional preprocessor statement does not allow it (a define in header3.h that would make header1.h or header2.h not to be included), yes.

Comment: Yes, header3 will have header1 declarations. And you will need only `#include "header3.h"`. But you can test this faster than writing question here and waiting for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, provided that there are no conditional compiling statements that may prevent such inclusions from happening.

For example, in this situation, header1.h won't be included from header3:

header2:

```
...
#ifndef THING
#include "header1.h"
#endif
...
```

header3:

```
...
#define THING
#include "header2.h"
...
```